# Copy home directory from one Mac to another both running macOS Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, copy-paste, rsync

I have a new 16" and an older 15" MacBook Pros both running macOS Catalina. I want to transfer all my the content in my home directory to the new MacBook Pro while retaining the same username.

How do I do this?

Different problems have occurred since I have a huge amount of data about 1.3TB of it to transfer.

1. With `scp -rp`: Over my local Wi-Fi network, it is slow and mainly, files with a too long full path are not copied.
2. With `rsync -aZv`: Slow here too and there are the same issue than with `scp` with the long full path of filenames to copy.
3. `By linking the 2 MacBook Pros with a Thunderbolt cable` : With **Shared directory**, too slow and I have had at each time errors that stops the copy, which is very frustrating.

So, how can I copy all this data (even with a long full path for files) on to the new MacBook Pro ?

i.e how to to be able to copy all the content of my `/Users/name/` directory into another directory of my new macbook pro 16", i.e into `/Users/name/home_from_old_macbook_15_inch/` ?

Comment: Is Migration Assistant an option?

Comment: Transfering 1.3TB over WiFi or wire will take some time with any method you use. What do you mean by "slow"/"would take too much time"? How long would it take with the methods you mentioned, how long would be acceptable?

Comment: @nohillside : The main issue is that I have some files not copied since the full path is too long with `scp` and `rsync` : how to circumvent this ? In the absolute, I don't want a very fast method but mostly to be able to copy all the content of my `/Users/name/`directory into another directory of my new macbook pro 16", i.e into `/Users/name/home_from_old_macbook_15_inch/` .

Comment: Your comment asks a different question than your question does. If some paths/files don't get copied with `rsync` or `scp` they may also fail with other approaches. Can you edit your question to focus on the actual problem and add the error messages you get (including the path/files in question).

Comment: Really your first and best option is Migration Assistant as it is *designed* to deal with anything the filesystem throws at it. Just create an admin user and make sure there is no account on the target Mac with the user account you are migrating. Target disk mode is probably fastest but you are limited by the connection method not by the software you use to transfer the files.

Answer (score 2):

Migration Assistant was designed by Apple to do just that.  A direct copy may have problems because some of the things in ~/Library depend on MAC address, and some may change due to differences in hardware or O.S. version.

With 1.3 TB, speed cannot be expected.

You’ll have to have nothing else running (not even Time Machine or Spotlight indexing) to avoid error -42.  According to http://www.macwizard.com/errors.html, that means “too many files open.”  If no other apps are running, then report to Apple that Migration Assistant has a bug.  Actually two of them—it should not open too many files, and if it does get that error, it should close some and keep going instead of quitting.

Comment: After a long time, I get a frustrating (-42 error) and I don't understand why ?

Comment: It amazes me that Apple for _fifty_ years has chosen not to improve their diagnostic messages.  CP/M and HDOS had more informative diagnostics in the 1970s.  I’ll add detail to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you undertake a method that not only copies the source directory from one machine to another but also copies that source to a third backup / archive drive. Time Machine + Migration Assistant has been mentioned. Another option is a third-party backup/archiving utility such as Carbon Copy Cloner. Finally, as you note, you can try to decode the right ways to do the transfer via the shell commands.

Set up the process to copy/clone/backup the source to the external drive. Let it run overnight as needed. Then, invert the process to copy/clone/restore the external drive to the new location drive. You worry over the time for the transfer when you can/should instead just do it right to devote the time needed to transfer the given amount of data robustly.

Answer (score -1):

I want to suggest to create a Time Machine backup of older 15" MacBook, then restore the backup in new 16" MacBook. Just configure Time Machine to exclude system files and applications for saving time and space.

The main issue must be the extra storage for saving the backup, but I'm quite sure that's not a problem since you have two MacBook Pro.

1. Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click Time Machine.
2. Click: Options…
3. Click check box for: Exclude system files and applications
4. Click: Save
5. Create a backup.

Use this link as reference:
[Exclude files from a Time Machine backup on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/exclude-files-from-a-time-machine-backup-mh15622/mac)

Comment: Migration Assistant can restore files from a Time Machine backup or directly from the original account.  And (except for bugs), it is smart enough to skip or modify things incompatible with the destination.  It also allows you to select only a user account for transfer.